# How to use locale for Java ZoneId?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, datetime-format, zoneid

Having an issue when translating my date to other languages. The way its displayed right now is
`h:mm:ss a VV`. My issue is if I swap my locale to zh_TW, it displays as `下午11:59 Asia/Shanghai`.

I'd like to have the `Asia/Shanghai` part to be translated to the correct Locale as well. How would I do this?

I have tried using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss a VV", locale)` but the zone id (VV) part only shows in English.

Comment: What's the expected output? Is it something like `6:58:51 下午 中国时间`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the translation would be for that, but I expected it to be translated when I passed the locale in

Comment: @deHaar is this zone id component not translatable? also, I think `中国时间` is simplified so it's not correct for zh_TW

Comment: I don't think that is to be expected…The translation I got is the result of `ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai").getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.CHINESE);`

Comment: @deHaar There is no country in `Locale.CHINESE`. If you use `new Locale("zh", "tw")`, it does produce traditional chinese.

Comment: Good point @Sweeper, thanks! I'd prefer `Locale.of("zh", "tw")` over the deprecated constructor, but not using `Locale.CHINESE` in that statement does indeed produce a different output, though I just can't tell if it's Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese or Chinese at all…

Comment: @BarryTone do you want this as zone id: `中国标准时间`?

Comment: @deHaar I believe that's still simplified, but this actually might help. Do you know where I can find the list of the FULL_STANDALONE timezones?

Comment: @BarryTone It's all in the [CLDR](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr). That is sorted by locale though, which you might find rather inconvenient.

Comment: Well, that one was actually produced by formatting some time with a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss a zzzz", Locale.of("zh", "tw"));`. You can try it with Asia/Bahrain, too, but use a `Locale.of("ar", "bh")` or something similar…

Comment: Are you quite sure you users want *Asia* and *Shanghai* translated? `Asia/Shanghai` is a technical ID and was never meant for end users. While I don’t know Taiwanese users, I think that most users prefer *China Standard Time* or *中國標準時間*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my output needs to be Region/(City or Country)

The two parts in time zone IDs like `Asia/Shanghai` are not supposed to be translated separately.

You *can* however, get an "exemplar city" for a timezone. This is one of the many things that [CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/index) records. I am not aware of a standard Java API for getting the exemplar city, but you can use the [CLDR engine](https://github.com/Squarespace/cldr-engine-java) library ([Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squarespace.cldr-engine/cldr-engine/1.2.3)).

Suppose I want to find an exemplar city of `Asia/Shanghai` localised for `ar-BH`.

```
var cldr = CLDR.get("ar-BH");
System.out.println(cldr.Schema.TimeZones.exemplarCity.get(cldr.General.bundle(), "Asia/Shanghai"));
```

Output:

```
شنغهاي
```

If you also want the localised name of the continent ("Asia" in `Asia/Shanghai`), you can use `getRegionDisplayName`.

```
System.out.println(cldr.General.getRegionDisplayName("142", DisplayNameOptions.build()));
```

Note that I passed "142", which is apparently the [UN M49](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M49) ID for Asia. See the list of the available IDs [here](https://phensley.github.io/cldr-engine/docs/en/api-regionidtype). There is only a small number of options for the part before the `/` in IANA zone names. It shouldn't be too difficult to maintain a mapping from "Asia" to "142", "Europe" to "150", etc.

Comment: I didn’t know there was a CLDR library for Java.  I may have to update [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73959786/is-there-an-implemented-way-to-convert-iso-8601-period-to-a-translated-string-re/73989173#73989173) of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that "V" resolves the **timezone-id**, which is not meant to be translated as simple text. Try using the **timezone-name**, defined by a lower case `z`. This can be translated using a present Locale.

Comment: timezone-name is Pacific Standard Time and such right? it won't work for me unfortunately, my output needs to be the `Region/(City or Country)`

Comment: @BarryTone Umm, that's what you actually want? That is not possible - as far as I know there is no such list of localised "zone ids" in the CLDR.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, my problem actually stems from a client in Bahrain. In the IANA, they have their timezone-name as `AST or Arabic Standard Time`. But the client says this is wrong, and they want a display such as `Asia/Bahrain` or anything with their country's name in it.